# how to make methods add to arraylist

Tags: java, methods

how do i 
make A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account and then add the
transaction to the ArrayList of transactions.
 A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account and then then add the
transaction to the ArrayList of transactions.

```
package hw1josezaragoza;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author jose
 */
public class Hw1josezaragoza {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Account acc = new Account(1122, "George", 1000);
    acc.deposit(3000);
    acc.withdraw(2500);
    acc.setInterestRate(1.5);
    acc.getMonthlyInterestRate();


    System.out.print("The account holder's name: " + acc.getName()
            + ".\nThe annual interest rate: " + acc.getInterestRate()
            + ".\nThe balance: " + acc.getBalance() 
            + ".\nThe monthly interest: " + acc.getMonthlyInterest() 
            + "\nAccount created on " + acc.getDate());


        }
 }
```

**Transaction Class:**

```
class Transaction {

    private Date dateOfTrans;
private char typeOfTrans;
char WithDraw = 'W';
char Deposit = 'D';
private double amount;
private double balance;
private String description;

public Transaction(char Type, double newAmount, double newBalance, String newDescription, Date date) {
    typeOfTrans = Type;
    amount = newAmount;
    balance = newBalance;
    description = newDescription;
    dateOfTrans = date;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return dateOfTrans;
}

public char getType() {
    return typeOfTrans;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
    }
}
```

**Account Class:**

```
class Account {

    private int Id = 0;
private String name;
private double balance = 0;
private double annualRate = 0.0;

private Date dateCreated = new Date();
private ArrayList Transaction = new ArrayList();

Account() {
    Id = 0;
    balance = 0.0;
    annualRate = 0.0;
}

Account(int newId, double newBalance) {
    Id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
}

Account(int newId, String newName, double newBalance) {
    Id = newId;
    name = newName;
    balance = newBalance;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int newId) {
    Id = newId;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
    balance = newBalance;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public double getInterestRate() {

    return annualRate;
}

public void setInterestRate(double annualRate) {

    this.annualRate = annualRate/100;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public void setDate(Date newDate) {
    dateCreated = newDate;
}

double monthlyInterestRate;
double monthlyInterest;

public double getMonthlyInterestRate( ) {
    monthlyInterestRate = annualRate / 12;
    return monthlyInterestRate;
}

public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    monthlyInterest =balance * monthlyInterestRate;
    return monthlyInterest;
}

double withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
    return balance;
}

double deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;

    return balance;


  }

}
```

Comment: StackOverflow guidelines: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: You've already got `deposit()` and `withdraw()` methods.  You've even already declared your transactions `ArrayList`.  I don't understand what difficulty you are having in creation a `Transaction` and adding it to your list.

Comment: @azurefrog Judging by his ArrayList declaration, I'm guessing he's not sure either A) how to use one, or B) create an ArrayList of transactions.

Comment: The fields `WithDraw` and `Deposit` in your `Transaction` class probably should be _constants_ (i.e., `static final char WITHDRAW = 'W'` and `static final char DEPOSIT = 'D'`)

Comment: @DrewKennedy I figured as much from seeing `ArrayList Transaction` instead of `ArrayList<Transaction> transactions`, but the OP still needs to edit his post to ask a specific question.  I'm not going to do someone's homework based on what I *think* they don't understand... ;-)

Comment: @azurefrog I would, but I expect compensation ;)

Comment: im not sure how to add the transactions that occured into the array list transaction

Comment: @jose Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), take a stab at writing the code.  If it still doesn't work, come back and ask a *specific* question about what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't name your arraylist the same as one of your classes. Assuming you change the arraylist's name to transaction, insert the following code at the end of the withdraw method.

```
transaction.add(new Transaction("W", amount, balance, "Withdrawal", new Date()));
```

And this into the deposit method.

```
transaction.add(new Transaction("D", amount, balance, "Deposit", new Date()));
```

Additionally, it's recommended to change your arraylist declaration statement to the following:

```
private ArrayList<Transaction> transaction = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
```

Comment: i got it. also i ended up putting a @Override public String toString(){   return ;   }   but im confused on what it has to return